# Calculate the probability of circuit breakage (Geometric Probability)

Tags: probability

A breakage of the electrical circuit occurs if either an element K1 or both elements K2 and K3 break. The elements K1, K2, K3 break independently of each other with probabilities respectively 0.3, 0.2, 0.1. Calculate the probability of circuit breakage.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: [How To Ask A Homework Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: If you search for “circuit probability” here, you will find many examples of how to solve this sort of problem.

Comment: Haven't tried anything as for now, because I'm still trying to understand better classical probability, just hoped to get a solution, so in the future I'll have something to compare my own solution to.

Okey amd, I'll try to search for “circuit probability”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Events $A_1, A_2, A_3$ denote the failure of $K_1, K_2,K_3$ resp.

Probability that system fails= $P(A_1 \cap \overline A_2 \cap\overline A_3)+P( A_1 \cap  A_2 \cap A_3)+ P(\overline A_1 \cap  A_2 \cap A_3)$

$=P(A_1 \cap \overline A_2 \cap\overline A_3)+P(A_2 \cap A_3)$

$=(0.3)(0.8)(0.9)+(0.2)(0.1)$

Comment: A huge thanks @Mathsmerizing, you're my savior, have a wonderful day :)

Comment: You are welcome @Jack